# awk how to remove duplicates in a field except for some specific strings

Tags: string, awk, duplicates

This is the structure of my csv file:

```
Oslo        Company1           Mission1
Oslo        Company1           Mission2 
Oslo        Company3           Missionspecial 
Oslo        Companyspecial     Missionspecial
Paris       Company2           Mission1
Paris       Companyspecial     Mission2 
Paris       Company3           Missionspecial
```

I want to delete all duplicates in fields 1,2,3 and replace them with blanks, except for those special strings "Companyspecial" "Missionspecial" so that the output is:

```
Oslo        Company1             Mission1
                                 Mission2
            Company3             Missionspecial
            Companyspecial       Missionspecial
Paris       Company2             
            Companyspecial       
                                 Missionspecial
```

All I know to do is remove all duplicates with this bit of code:

```
x[$1]++ {$1=""}x[$2]++ {$2=""}x[$3]++ {$3=""}){print $1,$2,$3,et.....}
```

I'm no programmer. Help would be greatly appreciated, will save hours of stupid slave work! Thank you much in advance!``

Comment: post a job at vworker.com, and give some poor coder in a third-world country a chance to make a few bucks?

Comment: This does not really play to AWKs strengths.  It's not hard to do in general, but it's kinda hard to tell you how to do it.

Comment: to jcomeau_ictx: I am expected to go through 10 years of Excel spreadsheets, print them, and go through them with a green marker. It's my fate these days and I'm trying to ease my burden learning some stuff that could help me !

Comment: To caveman: I discovered awk 10 days ago and I am all too aware of its strengths! If I'd gotten to its strengths a couple of months ago, I would have saved a LOT of time!

Comment: @user535684 Did a minor change to my code to shore up your concerns about repeated text in different columns.

Comment: use "@user535684" instead of "to user535684" to call a comment to someone's attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    if($i !~ /(Mission|Company)special/)
      if(a[i,$i]++)
        $i=""
  printf("%-12s%-19s%-s\n",$1,$2,$3)
}'
```

Proof of concept [HERE](http://www.ideone.com/wo498)

#### Edit

Updated code to reflect concerns about one field's text potentially removing another. I accomplish this by changing `a[$i]++` to `a[i,$i]++` so that each field's text is also tied to the field number.

Comment: +1.  I didn't know the ++ operator would do that on an array ... or at least I didn't remember it today.  Nice.  Depending on the input, it might need a separate duplicate array for each column.  For example, if Paris was in the third column, this would remove it.  On the other hand, that might be the desired result.  The OP doesn't say.

Comment: Thank you. Your code seems to work, although, I have a doubt about some blank "cells" on further fields being removed, and the articulation of this script with the previous one I run (when I did not have to preserve some "special terms", the problem did not occur). I am sorry though, but I'll have to go through this in further detail tomorrow as it is very late here. Thanks again, and hope I can get back to you.

Comment: trying again: yes, words like Paris can be repeated in different columns though as strings in a sentence (I have columns of "comments" in other fields). Well, I'll run through this with a clearer mind tomorrow (discoverd awk 10 days ago!)