# awk how to remove duplicates in fields only if previous fields are the same

Tags: awk, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from fields (and replace them with blanks) only if the previous fields are the same. For example:

Sample input:

```
France  Paris      Museum of Fine Arts          blabala
France  Paris      Museum of Fine Arts          blajlk
France  Paris      Yet another museum           lqmsjdf
France  Paris      Museum of National History            mlqskjf
France  Bordeaux   Museum of Fine Arts          qsfsqf
France  Bordeaux   City Hall                lmqjflqsk
France  Bordeaux   City Hall                    lqkjfqlskjflqskfj
Spain   Madrid     Museum of Fine Arts          lqksjfh
Spain   Madrid     Museum of Fine Arts          qlmfjlqsjf
Spain   Barcelona  City Hall                nvqjvvnqk
Spain   Barcelona  Museum of Fine Arts          lmkqjflqksfj
```

Desired output:

```
France    Paris        Museum of FineArts                    blabala
                                                             blajlk
                       Yet another museum                    lqmsjdf
                       Museum of National History            mlqskjf
          Bordeaux     Museum of Fine Arts                   qsfsqf
                       City Hall                             lmqjflqsk
                                                             lqkjfqlskjflqskfj
Spain     Madrid       Museum of Fine Arts                   lqksjfh
                                                             qlmfjlqsjf
          Barcelona   City Hall                              nvqjvvnqk
                      Museum of Fine Arts                    lmkqjflqksfj
```

Thank you much in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You might be able to do this in `awk` using functions, but why? It seems like a better fit for a more general-purpose language. Perhaps Python using the `csv` module? Also, unless this is the final step, it's probably a bad idea, because it makes it harder to parse the file in the future.

Comment: I have a script which accomplishes almost the same here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785566/awk-how-to-remove-duplicates-in-fields-only-if-previous-fields-are-the-same, but I have to keep the names of institutions that come back frequently. So it takes time to isolate them (1500 lines). As to the output, it serves my purpose because the file is processed as LaTeX somewhere down the road.

Comment: That's a link to the current page. Perhaps you meant [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393245/awk-how-to-remove-duplicates-in-a-field-except-for-some-specific-strings).

Comment: Are the records in order? Specifically, would "France Paris Yet..." ever appear between the two "France Paris Museum..."? Also, are the fields tab-delimited (no spaces except within fields and no tabs within fields)?

Comment: @Dennis: yes, I meant that script! That is how I got my work done so far until I realized I could do better (hum... "someone" could do better). I had not then completely analyzed the problem (was swamped, actually). And yes, the data is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {if ($1 == prev1) $1 = ""; else prev1 = $1; if ($2 == prev2) $2 = ""; else prev2 = $2; if ($3 == prev3) $3 = ""; else prev3 = $3; print}' inputfile
```

Here is a shorter version that works for any number of fields (the last field is always printed):

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {for (i=1; i<=NF-1;i++) if ($i == prev[i]) $i = ""; else prev[i] = $i; print}' inputfile
```

The output won't be aligned for on-screen use, but there will be the correct number of tabs.

The output will look like this:

```
field1 TAB field2 TAB field3 TAB field4
TAB TAB TAB field4
TAB TAB field3 TAB field4
TAB field2 TAB field3 TAB field4
etc.
```

If you need columns aligned, that is also possible.

**Edit:**

This version allows you to specify the fields to deduplicate:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"; OFS=FS
    deduplist=ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1]=""
    split(deduplist,tmp," ")
    for (i in tmp) dedup[tmp[i]]=1
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF;i++)
        if (i in dedup) {
            if ($i == prev[i])
                $i = ""
            else
                prev[i] = $i
        }
    # prevent printing lines that are completely blank because 
    # it's an exact duplicate of the preceding line and all fields 
    # are being deduplicated
    if ($0 !~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) 
        print
}
```

Run it like this: `./script.awk "2 3" inputfile` to deduplicate fields 2 and three.

Comment: the first script does not work at all. The second works great except that it will cause problems in "further" fields as they are likely to contain replicate data I want to keep (ie, "Letter", "Report",...). In other words, I'd rather be able to control on which fields I remove duplicates (but you're still my genius!).

Comment: @Trying: That's weird because the two are doing basically the same thing. See my new version for a way to select the fields to remove duplicates for.

Comment: That works perfectly well. What a great script! It is very flexible. That might make me the woman every one needs around the (small) workplace (still very low pay). Since I don't know how to thank you (besides marking the answer as accepted), here is my small thank-you to you: http://i.imgur.com/G7UE2.jpg My supervisor is great. I'll drill in that if she gets her goddamn pdf the way she wants it, it is because of Dennis Williamson, and she can only thank me for working overtime (but then, I get in late! --hey, can't have it both ways!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl one-liner:

```
perl  -F"\t" -nae '@O=@F;if(!$x){$x=1}else{for($i=0;$i<=$#S;$i++){$F[$i]=""if($S[$i] eq "" || $S[$i] eq $F[$i])}};print join "\t",@F;@S=@O;'
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/RvgBw)

I've assumed the fields are tab separated.

Comment: the script does not work for me. It just indents the first field when it is the second occurence of it. And it is the first time I am using perl...

Comment: @Trying: Is the input tab-delimited? I've given a working link on ideone, please see it.